# Excluding a value when null is present in the column

Tags: sql

I want to filter the table without the row c

| column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 100 |
| b | 200 |
| c | 50 |
| null | 200 |

Desired output

| column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 100 |
| b | 200 |
| null | 200 |

I tried

```
select *
from table
where column1 <> 'c'
```

But since I can compare with null, I'm getting the wrong output. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `null` as follows:

```
select * from table where column1 <> 'c' or column1 is null
```

Or you can use the `coalesce` function as follows:

```
select * from table where coalesce(column1,'cc') <> 'c'
```

`Coalesce` will replace the `null` value in `column1` with the value provided as the second argument. I have used the value which is not equal to `'c'` so records with `column1` as `null` will pass this condition

Comment: Select * from table where column1 <> 'c' or column1 is null, here wouldn't it return just the rows with null values, since we are giving column1 is null.

Comment: But we have used OR between the conditions so it will return the result that you have mentioned in the desired output a,b, and null

Answer (score 1):

ANSI SQL, `DISTINCT` predicate.

```
select *
from table
where column1 is distinct from 'c'
```

However, not supported by all dbms products.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=13a1a6ab5e6d5b3a4ce4d35891370020